# Is possible to have a Title (on axis) that rotates when draggable box (3d) rotate?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to change some things in the graphic "3D scatter chart Draggable Box"

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/grid-light

Is possible to add a title to an axis, but that it rotates when I turn the box?

Now, if i add a title in this way:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
            text: "Latitude"
           }    
       },
```

When i rotate the box, the title doesn't follow the yAxis....

This is the code to rotate the chart:

```
     $(chart.container).bind('mousedown.hc touchstart.hc', function (e) {
                    e = chart.pointer.normalize(e);
            var posX = e.pageX,
            posY = e.pageY,
            alpha = chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha,
            beta = chart.options.chart.options3d.beta,
            newAlpha,
            newBeta,
            sensitivity = 5; // lower is more sensitive

            $(document).bind({
                'mousemove.hc touchdrag.hc': function (e) {
                    // Run beta
                    newBeta = beta + (posX - e.pageX) / sensitivity;
                    newBeta = Math.min(100, Math.max(-100, newBeta));
                    chart.options.chart.options3d.beta = newBeta;

                    // Run alpha
                    newAlpha = alpha + (e.pageY - posY) / sensitivity;
                    newAlpha = Math.min(100, Math.max(-100, newAlpha));
                    chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha = newAlpha;

                    window.alphaOn3dGraph = newAlpha;
                    window.betaOn3dGraph = newBeta;

                    chart.redraw(false);
                },
                'mouseup touchend': function () {
                    $(document).unbind('.hc');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I asked our developers about that

Comment: Unfortunately at this moment it is not possible, but you can try to call [axis.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update) and modify rotation parameter.

Comment: maybe, but i think that i can't try because for me is too difficult...  but thanks